# What are the prerequisites for Fulton's "Intersection Theory"?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, schemes, intersection-theory

Is it necessary to read SGA VI to understand "Intersection Theory" by William Fulton?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, SGA VI it is neither necessary nor sufficient!
Beware that whatever your prerequisites Fulton's book is incredibly difficult .
 I would advise you to concentrate on chapter one and to take your time for digesting the rich but concisely explained material there.

A great strategy would be  to simultaneously read [Eisenbud-Harris's online treatise](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC0QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fisites.harvard.edu%2Ffs%2Fdocs%2Ficb.topic720403.files%2Fbook.pdf&ei=LH7gU93zGOmo0QXLroH4CQ&usg=AFQjCNGq7VLTT46J7okQJYclPI6TzbBtpg&bvm=bv.72197243,d.d2k), which is very user friendly and  accompanied by  a mind-boggling  collection of beautiful geometric illustrations of the theory.
Finally, as a road map, here is [Kiritchenko's elementary Introduction](http://www.hse.ru/data/2014/05/13/1321520113/Intersection%20Theory_Lectures1-9.pdf) to Intersection Theory.

**Historical remark**
The main impetus for intersection theory was to make Schubert's calculus (a very prophetic theory much in advance to its contemporary algebraic theory techniques)  rigorous: this was exactly Hilbert's fifteenth problem.
Intersection theory was at the heart of 20th century algebraic geometry and Weil's notorious [*Foundations of Algebraic Geometry*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_algebraic_geometry?oldid=575675435)  were essentially devoted to providing rigorous foundations in all characteristics for intersection theory.
Scheme theory, including  Fulton's important results, provided a a definitive and satisfactory  frame for the modern foundations of intersection theory.
His  book "Intersection Theory" is the distillation of more than a century's research in this fundamental and difficult field.
It is thus not surprising that the resulting  compact tome is necessarily so concise and hard to read .

Comment: The link to Eisenbud and Harris's article is now down, is there a new link?

Comment: @mi.f.zh     Unfortunately no, I think. The book now exists and I suppose the Editor forced the authors to withdraw the online version.

Comment: Ah, is this just the 3264 book?

Comment: @mi.f.zh Yes, it was the preliminary version, made freely available to their students.

Comment: Is [this link](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/joeharris/files/000-final-3264.pdf) okay?